# how to solve "rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken" in stanford model toolbox

Tags: java, scala

When I run the scala program "stanford model toolbox",  it show me the message
`"'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)'` is broken"
How can I solve it???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error usually occurs when you use Java 8 with an older version of sbt; try setting your JAVA_HOME to an older JVM like so:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
```

Comment: I have set the JAVA_HOME as "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79" but it still show this message:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken"
My OS is windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by finding the right JDK version with scala.
https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html